# Python: Cannot open directories starting with letters a,b,f,r,t,v and numbers 0-7

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, directory

In python, I am currently not able to open directories starting with the letters a, b, r, f, t, v and starting with numbers 0 - 7. What is it that I might be doing wrong? I can open other directories and files. I am using python 2.7.10 and Enthought Canopy as IDE. Please help me.

Comment: Give us an example. Is there a backslash in front of the directories name ? If yes: try two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're specifying pathname component separator in string literal (especially in Windows), you need to escape them to avoid interpret them as escape sequences (`\a` - bell, `\b` - backspace, `\f` - form feed, `\r` - carriage return, `\t` - tab, `\v` - vertical tab, ...):

```
>>> 'C:\a'
'C:\x07'
>>> print('C:\a')
C:
>>> print('C:\\a')
C:\a
```

Or use raw string literal:

```
>>> print(r'C:\a')
C:\a
```

Comment: I am not able to get to the root of the problem but at least I can solve it now.

Comment: @JayMehta, The point is: `'\a'` is not `'\ '` + `'a'`, but `'\x07'`.

Comment: JayMehta, @falsetru's answer does get to the root of the problem. I suggest that you study what is meant by an "escape character" (backslash in this case) or "escape sequence".